# CocoaPods not building target for Crittercism

Tags: ios, cocoapods, crittercism

I added `pod 'CrittercismSDK'` to my `Podfile` and ran `pod install`, it finished with no error, all good.

Using `import Crittercism` gives `No such module` error. I looked into the `Pods/` directory, there source code is there; however, the `Pods` project doesn't have a target called `Pods-MyProject-Crittercism`  (but it does have targets for each dependency).

Build keeps failing because the import isn't found. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm using `use_frameworks!` directive in my `Podfile`, and I have another `obj-c` library that works fine, so I don't know why this one isn't working.

Comment: Have you opened your project with the .xcworkspace file ?
Then, and only then, you can build (cmd + B) and then import

Comment: Yes, as I said, every other dependency works, except this one

Comment: Can you post your podfile please? It might be something to do with the way it's configured.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a general answer, I have found that:

1. Not using `#use_frameworks`
2. Using a `Bridging-Header.h` containing `#import "Crittercism.h"`
3. Not importing `CrittercismSDK` in the `Swift` class, but merely executing `Crittercism.enableWithAppID("appId")` does the trick.

Comment: if you don't include use_frameworks! in the Podfile, will it causing any possible dependency issues? The official guide recommend to include.

Comment: Since tou have to pick ome or the other, and you are not using a framework, you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

See if below steps helps in your case. What version of pod/Xcode in use? It will be great if you can share your pod file, thanks.

1. Install dependencies using Cocoapods and the use_frameworks! flag.
2. As you need to use a Objective-C dependency, create a Bridging header. You can create one easily by importing an Objective-C class to your Swift project, than remove it (the wizard should ask you if need a bridging header). Otherwise, create a new header file. Then, navigate to your target configuration and enter the name of your file in Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Objective-C Bridging header.
3. Still in your target configuration, add a new entry in Search Paths > User Header Search Paths: Pods as value and flag it as recursive.
4. Remove any import instruction from your code, relative to your Objective-C library.
5. Build your project. You should have a success.

Comment: It seems that when you have use_frameworks! in the podfile the bridging header is not necessary for the obj-c libraries.